# Cevelop -- setting C++ macro value at compile time from an environment variable?

Tags: c++, linux, macros, cevelop

In my existing compile command line I use this switch to define a macro from the command line:

```
 -DSsvid_UsrName=\"$USER\"
```

Using [Cevelop](https://www.cevelop.com/) 1.4, I added:

```
Project > Properties 
C/C++ Build > Environment
Environment variables to set > Add...

Name: Ssvid_UsrName
Value: ${USER}
```

After this I am getting the same error message. How do I verify that the `Ssvid_UsrName` macro has been set?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The environment contains environment variables like the PATH variables, etc.

Symbols for the compilation can be specified in the project properties: C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Symbols (Tab) -> Add...

[image]

Now you can observe the correct behavior in the output of the compile command in the console (I replaced my username with User in the picture):

[image]

I hope this helps!